# Getting error : Cannot implicitly convert type double to int are you missing a cast

Tags: c#

So I'm trying to make a simple CSGO Item value to key value calculator. I'm a beginner programmer and I'm getting this error. And after googling through this error I can't seem to find the problem. Anyone who can help?

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int itemValue = int.Parse(textBox1.Text);
    int Keys = itemValue * 0.8 / 2.15;

    label2.Text = "Value of item in keys:" + Keys;
}
```

Comment: _after googling through this error I can't seem to find the problem_  I dont know why but I find this hard to believe. And assuming you are using Visual Studio it should definitely tell you which line has the error. And there are thousands of answers explaining this. In fact if you just look at the error message it says: _"are you missing a cast"_

Comment: I'm missing a cast. It's because I haven't broken any bones.
:) Let's be nice to the new people. Although, @Fredric, googling the exact text of the error usually provides a quick solution. In this case, searching for "Cannot implicitly convert type double to int are you missing a cast" brought up 5 or 6 articles about this very problem.
Please feel welcome on stackexchange, but remember that many questions have already been answered. It's always best to search Google and the rest of stackoverflow.com before asking a question, especially as someone new to the language :)

Comment: Yes, but I couldn't find how to apply the fix to my problem, I didn't know what part to change.

Comment: I remember when I was there... You've got 3 assignments, one to a string-type property of a field, and two to local variables, and, if you don't have much other programming experience, or none with c-style languages, there's a good chance you don't even know what I'm talking about. Keep at it. I'm sure you'll be a useful contributor here in no time. And, seriously, take [the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour)!

Answer (score 6):

I'm kind of sad that this question's been downvoted. Yes, it's a simple question that's likely already been answered here, but as someone new to the language, how can you know what to search for? :)

See [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173105.aspx) for an explanation of casting and type conversions, and an example similar to your problem.

The error is on the line `int Keys = itemValue * 0.8 / 2.15;`.
This looks simple, but there are a few parts to it. Let's break it down.

`int Keys`
This first part is the variable declaration. You're declaring a variable called `Keys`. Its type is `int`. Pretty straightforward.

The second part is the assignment operator `=`. It's saying "I want `Keys` to be this value." Again, pretty simple.

The third part is the evaluation of everything on the right side of `=`, which boils down to some number with a decimal, right?

Your problem is that you've declared `Keys` as an `int`, but `itemValue * 0.8 / 2.15` is of type `double`, a different number format, that can't be converted to an integer (what would the program do with the decimal part of the number?).

So, you need to declare `Keys` as "`double Keys`" so it can store your result, or you need to get an integer value from your decimal number. You can do that by [casting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173105.aspx), or by using the `Round`, `Ceiling`, or `Floor` methods in the [`Math`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.math(v=vs.110).aspx) class.

Comment: OP here, thank you! This helps me to what to think about! Thanks for fast answer, and thanks for understanding!

Comment: When you hover over the downvote icon it states "This question does not show any research effort".. If you copy the error into google, I get 31,100 results. Downvotes are justified

Comment: Glad I could help. I noticed that you're a new user- welcome to stackoverflow! Please see my comment on your post. You should also definitely take [the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) to get familiar with how this community works. I've been a member for a while now, and it's really a phenomenal resource.

You should choose a best answer, upvote good comments and answers (even if they're not THE answer), & downvote negative or non-constructive comments and answers. I know that your voting is restricted as a new user, but voting is how stackoverflow works so well, so get in the habit of it.

Comment: Yes @Sayse, downvotes are certainly justified. It still makes me sad, though :P

It's also very important to explain why you downvoted, especially to new users like Fredric. At least 4 people downvoted, but only 1 person commented why.

Answer (score 1):

This `itemValue * 0.8 / 2.15` has as a result a double. You can't assign a double to an int.

You could overcome this like below:

```
int Keys = (int)(itemValue * 0.8 / 2.15);
```

which will cast this result to an `int`.

**Update**

I don't know if this is your intention. Pay attention on this that you will lose in accuracy doing so.

For example, the following console application

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        int itemValue = 2;
        int Keys = (int)(itemValue * 0.8 / 2.15);
        Console.WriteLine(Keys);

        double dKeys = itemValue * 0.8 / 2.15;

        Console.WriteLine(dKeys);

    }
}
```

outputs:

```
0
0.744186046511628
```

Please have a look [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/guBPsW).

So it depends on you, if you want to cast your result in an int or use the double. I mean we don't know what's `Keys`.

Comment: It looks as though the `Keys` is only used in a string so it would be better to just use a double. (wasn't my downvote)

Comment: It looks to me like the OP's code has been extracted from a larger code sample, so we can't really tell.

Comment: @Sayse makes sense that you are talking about. However, in any case   I can't get them.

Comment: @MatthewWatson sure thing that can be happened. However, I can't see the reason I got two downvotes earlier :).

Comment: OP here! Thank you! this helped, it doesn't round up which is good since it lets me give less keys for more value (huehuehue) Thank you alot for the answer though! There is nothing more to this simple simple calculator.

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do is do assign to an int variable a double value.

C# knows that, in that way you may lose data. Then it does not permit to do that.

What you can do is to change you code like this:

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
        double itemValue = Double.Parse(textBox1.Text);
        double Keys = itemValue * 0.8 / 2.15;

        label2.Text = "Value of item in keys:" + Keys;
}
```

Or, if you really know what you are doing:

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
        int itemValue = Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text);
        int Keys = (int) (itemValue * 0.8 / 2.15);

        label2.Text = "Value of item in keys:" + Keys;
}
```

but with this, you may lose value

You can read mode about this here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173105.aspx